# Sorting collection in java

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I have a `HashMap` which has keys as `Date` in `String`s and value as an `ArrayList` of custom objects. I want to sort this hashmap on the basis of key. How can I do that?

```
HashMap<String,List<ClassName>> hashmap = new HashMap<String,List<ClassName>>();
```

When `Hashmap` is like this:

```
{"2015/07/15 : List("Object1","object2","object3")
"2015/07/14 :List("Object4" , "Object5")}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Have a look at [Collections Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) for some more ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as using a sorted map (as others have suggested) you can easily sort the keys when you use them rather than when you insert them.

For example, in Java 8:

```
treeMap.keySet().stream().sorted().forEach(System.out:println);
```

A nice thing about this is that it's easy to sort using different comparators without changing the collection.

For example, if you wanted to to sort by the number of items in the list value:

```
treeMap.keySet().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(k -> treeMap.get().size()))
```

This method is good for situations in which you insert and change values in the map often and then occasionally need the keys sorted for a particular operation. You get the performance of a `HashMap` but the flexibility to sort however you want on use.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `TreeMap` instead of a `HashMap` . The `TreeMap`  implements the Sorted Map interface.

Comment: can i do it without using treemap?

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you can use `TreeMap` when you need a sorted map. However you are storing date value as Strings. Then it become harder to compare each. So i recommend to use `java.util.Date` instead of `String`. You can use a date formatter when you adding to the map. Use following code.

```
TreeMap<Date, List> treeMap = new TreeMap<>();
```

You can specify the `Comparator` in the constructor of the `TreeMap`. So it's easy to sort up things according to your custom order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TreeMap, if you need the sorted map.

If you don't want to use TreeMap, then get the key and sort it as below.

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    map.put("2015/07/15", list);
    map.put("2015/07/17", list1);
    map.put("2015/07/16", list1);

    ArrayList<String> keyset = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet());
    Collections.sort(keyset);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If i sort as Collections.sort(keyset) as suggested. WIll the map become sorted?